# JavaScript: How to reverse order=[] arrays from last to first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reverse

My js code does POST order.php?order[]=1&order[]=2&order[]=3&order[]=4&order[]=5&&action=update
How to **reverse it** to order.php?order[]=5&order[]=4&order[]=3&order[]=2&order[]=1&&action=update ?

```
JavaScript:
order=[];
//var reversed = $(this).sortable("serialize").split("&").reverse().join("&");
//var order = reversed + '&action=update'; //unfortunately it does not work so
$('#list ul').children('li').each(function(idx, elm) {
order.push(elm.id.split('-')[1])
});
$.post('order.php', {'order[]': order, action: 'update'});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="oreder-5">5</li>
    <li id="oreder-4">4</li>
    <li id="oreder-3">3</li>
    <li id="oreder-2">2</li>
    <li id="oreder-1">1</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will

```
order.reverse();
```

do the trick?

Comment: Thanks, Sean Kinsey! order.reverse(); before $.post(..); fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `order[]` as parameter name. Use `order[0]`, `order[1]`, etc as parameter name if ordering is important for the server side.

Comment: Then I don't see any need to reverse this.

Comment: It is for to update data in MySql database ORDER BY position DESC

Comment: Then ordering *is* apparently important.